# What are possible ways of handling multiple users accessing the same database via custom web API?

Tags: database-design, users, data-synchronization, web-server

I am very new to databases and Web design, but I understand enough to know that designing a good database is crucial, so I would like to prepare for that conceptually. However, I was unable to find any answers on my level on the web/in tutorials.

I am working towards a developing a database (MariaDB, to be exact) that will be accessed by my website (written in Django). I want the website to serve as an API for several people to work on the database. Naturally, I want to set some use- or group-specific privileges.

What are the possible ways of doing that, and what are their upsides and downsides?

I can only think of two generals approaches:

1. Connecting the website to the database as root, and letting the website API limit user capacity to edit certain tables.
2. Using some sort of server-side user system directly in a web API.

This is important to me both in the context of limited access to certain tables within a database and syncing multiple people editing the same table. Is there an approach generally considered as a good practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't connect as root/super user

Read this: [Multi-Tenant Data Architecture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx)

Since it's a web app, you're going to want to use connection pooling, for performance

This means you need to use **impersonation**, i.e., login as one user then switch to a different user. Because connection pooling requires that everyone in the pool connect with the same connection string.

For Maria/MySQL, read up on https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/grant/#proxy-privileges

MySQL/Maria doesn't yet do row security as far as I know, so you'd need to do your access control (via SQL) in the application layer (your web app)

In terms of multiple people editing the same rows at the same time, read up on [Optimistic Concurrency Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control)

Personally, I'd consider Postgres, as it does row security

Comment: A lot of terms I have never heard before, so it's definitely the right track—thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You want to definitely limit access on the SQL side.  You can create a login and then create a user on the SQL database and grant select on the table you want to allow access to.  Here is an [old StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998634/sql-server-2008-how-do-i-grant-privileges-to-a-username).